# Angular List Filled in constructor is Not defined in method

Tags: angular, devextreme, angular9

I have an Angular 9 component with a service injected in constructor and used inside the constructor to fill a list of a certain model as following:

```
 export class translationtasksComponent implements OnInit { 
    usertaskslist: UserTaskType[];
    constructor( public service3: UserService) {   
    service3.getTasks().subscribe(res => { this.usertaskslist = res as UserTaskType[] });
     }  
    }
```

inside the same component I have a 2 methods where I'm trying to use the previous list as following:

```
 getFilteredUsers(options) {
        return {
          store: this.usertaskslist,
          filter: options.data ? ["taskTypeId", "=", options.data.userTaskTypeTaskTypeId] : null
        };
      }

 setUserValue(rowData: any, value: any) {
        .
        .
         console.log( this.usertaskslist)
        .
        .
      }
```

the constructor is working well and filling the list.
also the first method is working fine but in the second method the list is returning "undefined".
I tried to call the service again inside setUserValue  method as a work around but the service is also undefined and not recognized as a service.

Note: I'm using .net core with Angular template.

the 2 methods are events fired by dxDataGrid from DevExtreme.

Comment: when are you triggering the second method? by any chance is it possible to trigger it before your subscription emits any value? you can also place an if block inside your subscription to check if the res holds any payload before assign it to your class property, due to asynchronous nature of it.

Comment: the constructor first fills the list and it is displayed well in html. after that the second method is triggered when I edit a cell value in the dxDataGrid which already show the list well. but the list is undefined in the event handler (setUserValue). The problem is I can't even get to the subscription of the service if I try to call it inside the second method as it's returning an undefined error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but I don't know if I'm understanding all the aspects of it.
It seems like the fired event (setUserValue) which is fired when editing a dxDataGrid cell does not have direct access to the component instance for some reason. But  it turned out that I can pass the component instance to it in constructor and then receive it in my handler and use it. and it works perfectly well  as following:

```
constructor(public service3: UserService) {
    service3.getTasks().subscribe(res => { this.usertaskslist = res as UserTaskType[] });
    .
    .
   let that = this,
   origOnSetCellValue = this.setUserValue;
   this.setUserValue = function () {
     origOnSetCellValue.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 0, 3).concat([that]));
   };

  }

.
.
setUserValue(rowData: any, value: any, currentData, componentInstance) {

    var currentUserId = currentData.userTaskTypeUserId;
    var currentTaskType = currentData.userTaskTypeTaskTypeId;
    var currentUserTask = componentInstance.usertaskslist;
}
```